# Accessibility options for both external monitors on MacBook Pro M1

Tags: display, dock, accessibility

I am using a MacBook Pro M1 2019 with a Dell D6000 docking station. I have two monitors plugged in to the docking station and use DisplayLink Manager to "extend" one monitor, i.e. the two monitors do not show the same picture, but one extends the other.

When making accessibility settings, such as inverting color, this is only applied to one of the two monitors. How can I make accessibility settings that affect both monitors?

If that is impossible, then I am also interested in workarounds that allow me to invert colors on both monitors.

Answer (score 0):

Please check Apple security that it isn't blocking Displaylink App. Go to System Preferences then Security & Privacy check under General tab that Displaylink isn't waiting for approval to allow to run. If no notification appears about Displaylink, check Privacy tab for "Screen recording" permission and enable it (will require reboot).
Notification I mentioned may look like this (5):
[image]

Detailed steps at https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/1188004

Comment: I checked in Security & Privacy under the General tab and Displaylink was not mentioned there as waiting for approval. After installing the Displaylink manager I gave it some permissions in the Security & Privacy area, but not in the General tab.